# GitKit Android Quick Start fails "Sign in with Google" with Error Code: 9

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit

I tried getting the GitKit Android Quick Start example to work. The SignUp and Login with Email work fine as far as I can see, so does the Facebook login, but whenever I try to use the Google signin, after choosing my Google account, I get a Toast "Error Code: 9". When debugging and looking into the GoogleIdpClient I can see that the error is thrown because the server responds with

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"backendError","message":"Error code: 9"}],"code":503,"message":"Error code: 9"}}
```

But I don't really believe that the google idp service is unavailable this whole time ..

When I use the Android Client ID to input it into the quickstart placeholders (instead of the Web Client ID, as asked by the tutorial) I get a GoogleAuthException with reason "Unknown".

I don't have a webserver running behind everything so far, so maybe GitKit doesn't like having no callback endpoints?

Any hints or ideas?

Thanks, Johannes

Comment: GitKit is a terrible name. Really makes me think of Git/Github integration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/auth-migration, Google has already migrated its sign-in to Google+ Sign In, even if the user doesn't use Google+.
It is possible to switch to new Google+ Sign In by setting

```
<meta-data
        android:name="identitytoolkit.use_google_plus"
        android:value="true" />
```

in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/reference/com/google/identitytoolkit/GitkitClientBuilder), it enables Google+ Sign In for Google accounts.

After setting this to true, I was able to get - and confirm - the Google+ permission dialog.

If you get error `INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE` afterwards, then you have to enable Google+ API in your [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

Comment: Works great. I heard that somehow Google-Accounts and Google+ accounts are now treated differently by the APIs. Maybe it has something to do with that..
Did you just stumble upon the solution by chance?

Comment: Well, actually I just tried and it worked. But, [according to this migration doc](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/auth-migration), Google+ Sign In completely replaced old OpenID 2.0, which has been shut down on April 30, 2015. So 503 error was probably appropriate. I'll update the answer.